# Is hashMap implemented as an array of linked lists

Tags: java, hashmap

While reading about `HashMap` I see that it is implemented as an array of buckets? Now are these buckets always linked lists? If so, why are they called buckets and not linked lists?

Comment: What programming language is this for? Suspecting Java

Comment: That kind of assumption has led to a famous DoS attack (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=750521). In retrospect, a linked list was a poor choice of bucket implementation, but Java is not going to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) tells us that it's implemented as an array of Entries:

```
transient Entry[] table;
```

Each Entry has a field `next`, so they create a single linked list structure:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
```

"Bucket" is a higher-level term, used in the literature and when explaining hash maps. Here "buckets" are implemented as a single linked lists.

Answer (score 4):

In Java's Hashmap, the buckets are implemented as a linked list (each `Entry` has a reference to another entry called `next`).

The term "bucket" is referring to a concept. Linked list an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Java, uses the concept of "Seperate Chaining" where it's implemented as an array of linked lists, in order to avoid collisions. 
This though, is not always the case. A hashmap can be implemented as an array entirely (linear probing); this though has a higher chance of creating a colission.

Regarding your question of "buckets". You could imagine a linked list as a bucket. However, if your HashMap implementation uses a proper HashFunction (algorithm to distribute your values in the hashmap array), your "buckets" only has, preferably, one item in it.